# Accessing people code variable in HTML Area

Tags: html, peoplesoft

Is there is any way with which we can able to access people code variable in HTML AREA declared as statically (with constant ).
same thing we are able to access with dynamically (Field Declaration ).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable as a bind like this peoplebooks example, on the peoplecode you will call to render the html:

> Example
>
> The following is the text in the HTML definition `TEST_HTML`:
>
> ```
> This is a %BIND(:1) and %BIND(:2) test.
> ```
>
> The following is the PeopleCode program:
>
> ```
> Local Field &HTMLfield;
> &string = GetHTMLText(HTML.TEST_HTML, "good", "simple");  
> &HTMLfield = (Record.CHART_DATA).HTMLAREA;  
> &HTMLfield.Value = &string;
> ```
>
> The output from `&string` (displayed in an HTML area control) is:
>
> `This is a good and simple test.`